# If S is a closed set, prove that $\partial S$=$\partial(\partial S)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If S is a closed set, prove that  $\partial S$=$\partial(\partial S)$.
I'm trying to prove this using the equation $\partial S$=cl($\partial S$)=int($\partial S$)$\cup \partial(\partial S)$, then we must have that int($\partial S$) is the empty set, how
should I prove this? What if S is an open set, is int($\partial S$) still empty? Please help me

Comment: If $S$ is closed, then $\partial S = S \setminus \operatorname{int} S$ and hence has no interior points.

Comment: An example for non-closed $S$ (in $\mathbb{R}$): $\partial \mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}$ and $\partial \mathbb{R}=\emptyset$.

Comment: Hint for "open" question: $\partial S = \partial (S^c)$.

Comment: @njguliyev: You should make an answer out of that last comment.

Comment: For the case if $S$ is open, can I argue that:

if $S$ open, then any $x\in S$ is an interior point of $S$, so there is an open ball of $x$, $N\cap S\ne \emptyset$.
Since $\partial S\not\subset S$, then $N\cap \partial S=\emptyset$. Since $\partial S=\partial (S^c)$ since S is open, then $N\cap\partial (S^c)=\emptyset$. so y is not an interior point of $\partial S$ and $int(\partial S)=\emptyset$.

Comment: @njguliyev : I like your comment.  I added a couple extra steps to prove the "obvious" fact that $S \setminus \partial S$ has no interior points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\partial S$ is the set of points, $x$, such that every neighborhood of $x$ intersects both $S$ and $S^c$.

Now since $S$ is closed, $\partial S \subseteq S$.

Thus, consider any point  $y\in \partial S$ and any neighborhood $U$ of $y$. Then $U\cap S^c \ne \varnothing$ by the definition of $\partial S$, but since $\partial S\subseteq S$ this means that $U \cap (\partial S)^c \ne \varnothing$ and hence there is no open set around $y$ contained in $\partial S$. That is, $y$ is not an interior point.

So we see that $\mathrm{int}(\partial S) = \varnothing$ like you wanted.

I'll let you think about the case where $S$ is an open set yourself now that you have this.